# How to improve select performance from huge tables

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, indexing, oracle11g

I currently have a process that is taking to long(an hour+-) .

The process basically does this :

First, it left joining from one table to a VIEW -

```
 SELECT * FROM 
 STG_CRM, V_CRM 
 WHERE
 STG_CRM.CRM_CASE_ID=V_CRM.CASE_ID(+)
```

The view DDL:

```
create or replace view stg_admin.v_crm as
select  t.case_id
from crm_case t, dim_crm x
where t.case_id=x.crm_case_id;
```

STG_CRM - 200k records - no indexes.

DIM_CRM - 90MIL records - indexed (crm_case_id - unique).

CRM_CASE - 200k records - no indexes.

Until now everything is not to heavy yet (about 2-3 minutes), then there is a left join to another VIEW , that currently is the heaviest select (just select * from the view is 10 minutes).

View DDL - I'm currently thinking over two different queries :

```
select t.crm_case_id,s.customer_key
from stg_crm t, stg_scd s
where t.account_number=s.account_number
and t.case_create_date  between s.start_date and s.end_date;
```

Or:

```
select t.crm_case_id,
       (select min(s.customer_key) keep (dense_rank first order by s.end_date asc)
        from stg_scd s
        where t.account_number = s.account_number and
              t.case_create_date <= s.end_date 
       ) as customer_key
from stg_crm t
```

Table stg_scd - 500MIL records indexed (customer_key,start_date,end_date) - UNIQUE partitioned by end_date daily.

Now currently both of this queries taking a very long time, the second a bit longer . My guess is because it is not using the index, since start_date is not beeing used to filter, but I have no idea how to add it.

My question is: How can I make it faster? If I add an index on STG_CRM on create_date, will it help?(I don't even know if DBA will allow at) because this is the small table.

**LIMITATIONS** :

1. I can't change indexes on the big table (STG_SCD)
2. I may be able to add index on other tables, but only given a good reason because it can hurt performances on other processes that use this tables.

**The implicit join syntax are generated through my program, so no need comments there.**

Thanks a lot in advance!

P.S. The first select left joined to the second select takes about 30-60 minutes .

Comment: Please, please, please migrate to using ANSI standard joins and stop using the old Oracle comma joins.

Comment: @MT0 Please read the 3rd line from the bottom before saying something like this...

Comment: I would propose to create an index as `CREATE INDEX IND1 ON stg_crm (account_number, case_create_date)` and (probably more important) `CREATE INDEX IND2 ON stg_crm (account_number)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this problem!

I was missing two things:

1) Statistics on stg_scd, which we disabled after we add partitions to the tables and forgot to add statistics after each partition is being added.

2) Adding index on stg_crm on(account_number, case_create_date)

Thanks for all your attempts :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are aggregating data from a very large table (as you are doing in your second query option), you might gain some performance benefits from using query_rewrite to calculate the results of these values in advance. Here's a paper that covers the use of this feature - 
http://gerardnico.com/wiki/database/oracle/query_rewriting

You can also find a lot of other examples for the best practices of using this feature, it is highly valuable in tuning data warehouse queries.

Good luck!